Code Failing to Execute after Building Application with PyInstaller
I am trying to package my Python web scraping application with PyInstaller to distribute to my coworkers, and I've just hit another roadblock. I found out how to properly get PlayWright packaged with app, but it seems I have a new problem. The code works fine when I run it from VSCode, but gets stuck when I run it from the .exe
def login():
    htmlstatusVar.set('Logging in...')

    pv_login = 'https://loffler.printfleet.com/login.aspx'
    report_url = 'https://loffler.printfleet.com/reportDetail.aspx?reportId=0afcca2e-f240-4ac3-ae81-438da7176e99'
    user = username.get()
    passw = password.get()

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless = False, )
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(pv_login)
        page.fill('input#txtUserName', user)
        page.fill('input#txtPassword', passw)
        page.click('input#cmdLogin')

        htmlstatusVar.set('Collecting report...')
        page.wait_for_url('https://loffler.printfleet.com/mast_home.aspx')
        page.goto(report_url)
        page.get_by_role("img", name="@").click()
        page.get_by_role("link", name="HCMC (1373)").click()
        page.click('#run')
        page.wait_for_selector('.pfReport')
        report = page.inner_html('#content')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(report, 'lxml')

        page.close()
        
    begin_report(soup)

def begin_report(soup):
    htmlstatusVar.set('Analyzing report...')
    global hValue, cValue
    hValue = int(html_hsptlValue.get())
    cValue = int(html_clncValue.get())
    location = html_location_dropdown.get()

I added page.close() to the end of the login() function because I had thought that the browser was staying open, preventing the code from moving on to the next function, but that did not solve the issue. These functions change the text of a button in my Tkinter UI, and when I run it, it never changes to "Analyzing report..." which indicates to me that the begin_report() function never runs. Any help you could offer me would be greatly appreciated.

Do it the old-fashioned way and use the logging module after every line to see exactly where it stalls (or better yet, make your button change text after every line, since you're already doing that)

Thank you for the tip! I was able to figure out that I didn't package an HTML parser for Beautiful Soup to use. I got lxml imported into my application and everything works! Thanks again!
